# How to ensure daily email is only sent once over multiple instances in Django app?

Tags: python-3.x, django, cron, apscheduler

I am trying to scheduling a job/CRON job, on Django app that uses APScheduler to send out a daily email at a scheduled time morning 9 AM. And We have 5 instances/pods in production.

The problem is each day I am getting 5 email and I suspecting its due to number of instance/pod. Cron is running on all instance/pod.

How to prevent the daily email from being sent out by all instances.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
def cron_job():
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(send_daily_emails, "cron", day_of_week='fri', hour=8, minute=0,
                          id="send_daily_emails_trigger", replace_existing=True)
    scheduler.start()
```

Python version - 3.5+
Django Version - 2.2.3
APScheduler  - 3.9.1

So this is run when my app initializes--this creates a background scheduler that runs the send_daily_emails function at 9AM each morning. The send_daily_emails function is exactly that--all it does is send email to couple of folks. My problem is that there are five instances of the app running, five separate background schedulers will be created and thus the emails will be sent five times each day instead of once. How to send only one email or stop other emails to go.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: It looks this flaw is already mentioned in django-apscheduler docs: be careful to ensure that you have only ONE scheduler actively running at a particular point in time. The simplest solution would be to run only on one instance? You can also run an scheduled AWS lambda function which can call an url on your django backend, which will fire the daily emails, basically it's free since you can get millions of http calls in the lambda free tier.

Comment: @jabez its a good idea to work on else you can also schedule cronjobs in any one instance if you are using a linux instance you can easily use the crontab feature for example * * * * * sleep 15; timeout 15s curl  'http://url/getposts/?key=######' you can  shedule cronjobs like this